# How to configure app engine static outbound IP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a server hosted on app engine. I need to call an API from it with a static outbound IP. I followed step-by-step the following guide https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/outbound-ip-addresses#static-ip

Now, I do not quite get how to configure the cloud NAT in order to call the external API through my static outbound IP (external IP address). I guess, I should call a local VPC address from my server and configure somewhere the API IP it should redirect to.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks a lot,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you configured everything per the doc you linked in your question, then you don't need to do anything special from within your AppEngine application.  Setting the Serverless VPC Access `egress_setting` to `all-traffic` means that anytime your AppEngine app tries to call an external address, it will be routed this way and will use the static IP configured as part of the setup.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this only for specific calls ? Moreover I did that and all calls would fail. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: Nope, you cannot specify to which endpoints this will be used. What error do you get?

Comment: Basically my server won't start because it cannot reach remote database endpoint.